# How to properly indent inline c++ lambdas?

Tags: neovim, filetype-c++

How can I change the behavior of smart indentation when I write a lambda function?

This is what I get right now:

```
    auto t  = std::thread([]{
                              std::cerr << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
                          });
    t.join();
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
    auto t  = std::thread([]{
        std::cerr << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    });
    t.join();
```

This is my configuration:

```
vim.opt.expandtab = true -- convert tabs to spaces
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 4 -- the number of spaces inserted for each indentation
vim.opt.tabstop = 4 -- insert 4 spaces for a tab
vim.opt.softtabstop = 4 -- number of spaces to use for autoindent
```

I also have Treesitter installed, with this configuration:

```
indent = { enable = true }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default (`:set cindent`) for C++ the indentation logic is controled by the `cinoptions`.

You can get an indentation logic closer to what you want by setting `cinoptions` to `(s`:

```
:set cinoptions=(s
```

I get something like:

```
    auto t  = std::thread([]{
        std::cerr << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
        });
    t.join();
```

More information on the different options using `:help 'cinoptions'`

If you need more control on the indentation you can set `cindentexpr` to a VimScript method to compute the indentation the way you like but this could be rather complex to do right for C++.

I would personally consider using a formater like the `clang` formater that you can integrate with Vim or Neovim ([clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format))

Comment: This works, but I had to disable treesitter indent option

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)